# Function to check for perfect square not working for large number

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, perfect-square

I came across an algorithm to tell if a given number is perfect square or not in O(logN) time.

Here is the implementation(JAVA) of the idea.

```java
public boolean isPerfectSquare(long x) {
        if (x <= 1)
            return true;
        
        long low = 1;
        long high = x;
        long mid = 0;
        while (low <= high) {
            mid = low + (high - low) / 2l;
            if (mid * mid == x)
                return true;
            else if (mid * mid < x)
                low = mid + 1;
            else
                high = mid - 1;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
```

This works fine for numbers like `256`, `808201` , etc
But fails for numbers like `999966000289`.

I cannot figure out why?

Comment: Maybe because mid*mid overflows.

Comment: Because numerical types in C have their limits. You should ask yourself what will be `mid * mid` when feeding it `999966000289` and would it fit into the `long` type you are working with. There is also a chance that `long` in your system can't even fit `999966000289` itself.

Comment: Makes sense now. Is there a way to check for square root property for large numbers?

Comment: @Insane_banda consider making `mid` a `long long int`.  And while you're at it, you can also use unsigned types for `low`, `high`, `mid`, to gain another factor of 2.

Comment: `999966000289` is a 40-bit number. Try `unsigned long long` for a limit of `18446744073709551615`.

Comment: you may want to experiment with [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: @pmg: Newton's method is efficient when you are close to the root. For initialization, it is better to find the closest power of 4 (easily done by shifts) and compute the same power of 2.

Comment: @DillonDavis this is a JAVA implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is that the intermediate `mid*mid` may overflow. It will help to use an unsigned type and a "long" or "long long" variant.

However, with the initial values of `low` and `high`, the first value of `mid` is close to `x/4`. If `x` is large, this is a great overshoot of the square root.

Hence, we can improve the range of manageable numbers by improving the initial `low` and `high` limit estimates.

Disclaimer: The Stack Overflow format is not suitable for long analysis. I have a good argument that the following works, part of which I have included below, but the full analysis is too lengthy to include here.

```
bool isPerfectSquare(unsigned long x) {
    if (x <= 1)
        return true;
        
    unsigned long low = 1;
    unsigned long high = x;

    // Improve the low/high limits
    while((low<<1) < (high>>1))
    {
        low <<= 1;
        high >>= 1;
    }

    unsigned long mid = 0;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2l;
        if (mid * mid == x)
            return true;
        else if (mid * mid < x)
            low = mid + 1;
        else
            high = mid - 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

With this modification, the initial value of `mid` is much smaller for large values of `x` and thus larger values of `x` can be handled without overflow.

It is not so difficult to show that the lower limit will not exceed the square root and doing that illustrates the intuition behind this method:

For some `t`, where `1<=t<2`, `x=t*2^r` for some integer, `r`. Thus:

```
    sqrt(x) = sqrt(t) * 2^(r/2)
```

which implies that

```
    2^(r/2) <= sqrt(x) < 2^(r/2+1)
```

Thus a lower limit is a binary `1` shifted until it gets halfway (when `r` is even) or as close as possible (when `r` is odd) to the leftmost 1-bit in the binary representation of `x`. This is exactly what happens in the `while`-loop.

Showing that `high` is indeed an upper bound of the square root after the `while`-loop requires a longer analysis.

Comment: "... but the full analysis is too lengthy to include here."  You're gonna need a bigger margin. :)

Comment: @rossum Yes, I am counting on this post to be famous in 300 years :-)